# C++ Custom Thread Wrapper with Templatized Constructor causes compile time error for insertion into std::map

Tags: multithreading, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, stdmap

I'm writing my own basic game engine and I'm multithreading it. I've created a `RawThread` object which wraps an `std::thread` with message queues, etc. I want to map these `RawThread`s to an id(`unsigned int`). So I try to insert one into an `std::map<unsigned int, RawThread>`, but I get a bunch of very ambiguous template errors. If I comment out the map.insert line, then the code compiles just fine, everything works, but I want to be able to insert a `RawThread` into the map, as tried in `main()`.

I've stared at this code for an hour, checking to see if I got my RawThread constructor template wrong, or if I'm using my references/pointer incorrectly, but I can't see the problem.

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <thread>

class RawThread
{
public:

    RawThread(const RawThread& you)
    {
        *this = you;
    }



    ~RawThread()
    {
        delete mThread;
    }

    template<class Function, class... Args>
    RawThread(Function&&f, Args&&... args)
    {       
        mThread = new std::thread(std::forward<Function>(f),         
                                          std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    const RawThread& operator=(const RawThread& in)
    {
        this->mThread = in.mThread;
        return *this;
    }

    void join()
    {
        mThread->join();
    }
    std::thread* mThread;
};



void hello(int x){while(true)++x;}

int main()
{
    int arg = 0;
    RawThread myThread(&hello, arg);
    unsigned int threadId = 0;
    std::map<unsigned int, RawThread> threadMap;
    threadMap.insert(std::make_pair(threadId, myThread));
    return 0;
}
```

I got a nasty looking error, so I put it on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/9A4wN7kL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `insert` is that a copy of `RawThread` is made by calling

```
template<class Function, class... Args>
RawThread(Function&&f, Args&&... args)
```

then `Function` is instance of `RawThread` and `Args` is empty. `std::thread` constructor can take instance of object as its first parameter but then the class of this instance must provide `operator()()` as the body of thread. Your class is missing that. You can add it and the code will compile.

```
class RawThread {
    //....
    void operator()() {}
};
```

But it is not what you want.

---

For me you should implement `RawThread` in the way that only one instance of this class keeps active `mThread` pointer. `RawThread` should be only moved, copies should be disabled. In case when many instances share the same `mThread` value, which one should call join or delete this object?

Version which supports only move may be:

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <thread>

class RawThread {
public:
    ~RawThread()
    {
        if (mThread)
        {
            if (mThread->joinable())
                mThread->join();
            delete mThread;
        }
    }

    RawThread(RawThread&& theOther) {
        mThread = theOther.mThread;
        theOther.mThread = nullptr;
    }

    RawThread& operator=(RawThread&& theOther) {
        mThread = theOther.mThread;
        theOther.mThread = nullptr;
        return *this;        
    }

    template<class Function, class... Args>
    RawThread(Function&&f, Args&&... args) {
        mThread = new std::thread(std::forward<Function>(f),         
                                  std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void join() {
        mThread->join();
    }
    std::thread* mThread;
};

void hello(int x){while(true)++x;}

int main()
{
    int arg = 0;
    RawThread myThread(&hello, arg);
    unsigned int threadId = 0;
    std::map<unsigned int, RawThread> threadMap;
    threadMap.emplace(threadId,std::move(myThread)); // move object into map
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>

class RawThread
{
public:

    template<class Function, class... Args>
    RawThread(Function&&f, Args&&... args)
    {
        mThread = std::make_shared<std::thread>(std::forward<Function>(f),
                                                std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    RawThread(const RawThread &)=default;
    RawThread(RawThread &&)=default;
    RawThread()=delete;
    void join()
    {
        mThread->join();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<std::thread> mThread;
};



void hello(int x){while(true)++x;}

int main()
{
    int arg = 0;
    RawThread myThread(&hello, arg);
    unsigned int threadId = 0;
    std::map<unsigned int, RawThread> threadMap;
    //This line is wrong because it uses the constructor template instead of the copy constructor
    //threadMap.insert(std::make_pair(threadId, myThread);
    threadMap.insert(std::make_pair(threadId, (const RawThread &)myThread));//Good, it uses the copy constructor
    threadMap.insert(std::make_pair(threadId, std::move(myThread)));//Good, it uses the move constructor
    return 0;
}
```